# Which branch of bitcoinj should I sync to?

Tags: segregated-witness, bitcoinj, segwit2x

I am experimenting with Bitcoinj to design a stable node that is synced.
Older versions of bitcoinj seem to drop connections and stop syncing.

I currently see the following branches (see screenshots).
[image]

I would assume to use the "release" branch but the latest one is "Unverified"

[image]

On the other hand, I am also inclined to use one of the active branches.
The Segwit has not been updated for 11 months. I recall reading on the mailing list that the segwit code is still not complete.

[image]

Instead of having to dig into the code myself, I would like to get opinions on which branch to use and save some time.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/issues/1336

> Just ran into this issue and spent a while debugging it (on latest release, 0.14.5). I added rpcserialversion=0 and that fixed the issue, so it's easy enough to work around. If bitcoinj isn't planning to add support for the new format, it might be nice for bitcoinj to realize it is parsing the new format, and throw a more relevant error message, something like "New rpc serial format not supported, see #1336".